# ui.bootstrap.dropdown keeps focus when other controls are clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use `Angular UI`'s `ui.bootstrap.dropdown` directive where I am facing a problem. After I cilck on the caret of the dropdown and then click on anywhere in the body, then if I try to click on a text field the text field immediately looses focus and the focus goes back to the caret of the dropdown button. I am however unable to produce this behavior in a plunker. But this behavior can be produced in the `Angular UI` demo page. To produce this behavior -

- goto https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown
- click on one of the caret button to bring up the menu
- click anywhere on the body to dismiss the menu
- scroll up to datepicker popup demo section
- try to place cursor in one of the text field
- the text field will immediately loose focus and the page will scroll down to the dropdown button caret which was initially clicked.

I am unsure on how to stop this from happening. Any help would be highly appreciated.

### Update

It seems this behavior only exists in version `2.3.1`. If I use `2.3.0` this doesn't happen. Here is a plunker which produces the same behavior - http://plnkr.co/edit/c4EGyxQD1vbksFWjnIGb

### Update

This is a bug in version `2.3.1` and has been raised in AngularUI Github.
Links to the issues given for reference -

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6364

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in version 2.3.2